# Python Selenium find_element only finds every second element by class

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, findelement

I want get every type of bet from this page (3-Way, Double Chance, etc.) but my script only returns every second element.

[image]

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://sports.tipico.de/en/event/552146710?t=match')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#_evidon-accept-button'))).click()
time.sleep(2)

for odds_rows in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='OddGroups-styles-event-details-odds-groups']"):
    odds_row = odds_rows.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'OddsRow-styles-odds-row')
    bet_type = odds_row.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'OddsCaption-styles-caption-cell-title').text 
    print(bet_type)
```

Result:

> 3-Way
>
> Handicap (0:1)
>
> Over/Under (1,5)
>
> Both teams to score?
>
> Who wins the 1.half?
>
> Even/Odd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPATH is incorrect now selected all 'OddGroups-styles-event-details-odds-groups' class divs from each CollapsibleItem.
Please change your script like this.

```
for odds_rows in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='OddGroups-styles-event-details-odds-groups']"):
    odds_row = odds_rows.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'OddsRow-styles-odds-row')
    bet_type = odds_row.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'OddsCaption-styles-caption-cell-title').text 
    print(bet_type)
```

to

```
for odds_rows in driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='ScoresOddsPage-styles-container']/div/div[2]/div").find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'OddsRow-styles-odds-row'):
    bet_type = odds_rows.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'OddsCaption-styles-caption-cell-title').text 
    print(bet_type)
```